# Writing text into and retrieving text from the text file using command line auguments

Tags: c++, text, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

Hello I want to write the output of my C++ Program in a text file using Command Line Argument then afterward retrieve it from the file . can you help me please I cannot get a satisfying code help.

Comment: Post what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything, SO is the wrong place to look for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are at a unix type command prompt (ie bash or similar), you can generally just redirect your output to a text file using '>'.  So if your program is called "MyCommand", just do:

```
    ./MyCommand > file.txt
```

After that, you can use a text editor to open the file, or anything else you'd do with a plain text file.

If you are trying to write out to a file programatically, you need to open up a file handle.  There are many ways to do this, one would be to use the standard file handling functions built into the C library.  See here for a tutorial:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm